# Versions of JQuery/JQuery UI in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I have an app that I am building, and the base code is from...

https://github.com/bokmann/rails3_fullcalendar

I upgraded the app to Rails 3.2.13, and implemented the asset pipeline for all the js and css files. The app was originally written with jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js. Our UI guy has started working, and he needs jquery-1.10.2.min.js. However, this breaks the calendar functionality. The errors I am getting in the FF web console when I load the calendar page are...

```
[14:13:56.871] SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate source map URL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead @ http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-1.10.2.min.js?body=1:1

[14:20:55.356] TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function @ http://localhost:3000/assets/calendar.js?body=1:48
```

I'm open to suggestions to either fix the calendar.js to be compatiable with the newest jquery, or is there a way to force the calendar to use the older version of jquery, and the rest of the app use the newest?

Comment: not quite sure how this makes the ui guy out of date, he's suggesting using the newest jquery.

Comment: The error you are getting doesn't suggest the `fulCalendar` is out of date, it suggests that it doesn't exist. besides, shouldn't that be `fullCalendar`?

Comment: I think that was just a typo. Here is what the js looks like... https://github.com/bokmann/rails3_fullcalendar/blob/master/public/javascripts/calendar.js Any reason jump out at anyone why this would not work? It works fine with jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js Is jquery and jqueryui the same thing?

Comment: @KevinB, Lumbee, my mistake, I thought that was 1.0.1 :) Lumbee, my humble suggestion, if that calendar is important to your app and it's hard to find alternative, better to fallback jQuery to whatever version to make it work. The former versions of jQuery is very powerful as well, at least I can't feel big difference between versions in normal usage.

Comment: I don't see any reason within the code that it wouldn't work, the problem is likely in the order in which the things are included. Look at your resources tab in the console, do you see jquery being included more than once?

Comment: Anything look out of place here? http://pastie.org/8443682